# How can I mount encrypted folder via SSH in Synology NAS?

Tags: ssh, mount, rsync, encryption, nas

Now I mount an encrypted folder:

1. open browser and login to NAS gui
2. click Control panel -> Shared Folder > Encryption > Mount
3. enter key
4. after folder is mounted:

   ```
   rsync -ah --progress --delete /path/* admin@ipadress:/volume1/path/
   ```

Can I bypass 1.-3. and use ssh only?

Comment: You're asking if you can run one ssh command that opens a browser, logs in to the NAS, clicks in specific places, enters a key, then runs an rsync command?

Comment: I can connect to NAS with ssh, therefore bypassing the gui altogether. If I can do this with ssh, I can automatize this process.

Comment: Does the key change every time?

Comment: No. The key is in an encrypted file, which I first open, then paste to NAS gui.

Comment: Does the "ssh" process need to open this encrypted file, or else how will the key be transmitted?

Comment: Good question. I assume there exists a command which mounts encrypted folder and has the key as argument.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the gui to mount the encrypted directory, then login to the synology as root over ssh and type `mount`. You will see a line like

```
 /volume1/@mycryptdir@ on /volume1/mycryptdir type ecryptfs (rw,relatime,ecryptfs_fnek_sig=88...,ecryptfs_sig=88...,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=32)
```

This shows your directory `/volume1/mycryptdir` is implemented on an underlying `/volume1/@mycryptdir@` directory using ecryptfs.  Unmount the directory with the gui, then try the following command:

```
# ecryptfs-add-passphrase
Passphrase:
```

Type in the cleartext passphrase you originally used (not the .key file). It will reply

```
Inserted auth tok with sig [88...] into the user session keyring
```

Now type the mount command using the options you saw before. You will need to create the mount point directory:

```
# mkdir /volume1/mycryptdir
# mount /volume1/\@mycryptdir\@/  /volume1/mycryptdir/ -t ecryptfs -o rw,relatime,ecryptfs_fnek_sig=88...,ecryptfs_sig=88...,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=32
```

Your filesystem should now be mounted and useable. You should now clear the password from the in-memory keyring:

```
# keyctl clear @u
```

When you have finished, unmount the directory with `umount /volume1/mycryptdir`.

Comment: Or perhaps more directly: https://superuser.com/a/1104513/402193